# Getting Request and Session in Symfony 3 Controller

Tags: php, symfony

I have a big problem and please help me. So I want to create an login system witch will use only users from :

```
providers:
  in_memory:
      memory:
          users:
```

So my global routing : `/app/config/routing.yml` :

```
app_admin:
    resource: "@AppAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /admin
```

My routing in AdminBundle :

```
app_admin_homepage:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: AppAdminBundle:Login:index }
login:
    path:   /login
    defaults:  { _controller: AppAdminBundle:Login:login }
login_check:
    path:   /login_check
```

My LoginController :

```
<?php

namespace App\AdminBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
public function indexAction()
{
    return $this->render('AppAdminBundle:Member:login.html.twig');
}
public function loginAction()
{
    $request = $this->get('request');
    $session = $this->get('session');

    if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } else {
        $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }

    return $this->render('AppAdminBundle:Member:login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
        'error'         => $error,
    ));
}
}
```

My login.html.twig :

```
<form class="login-form" action="{{ path('login_check') }}">
    <div class="login-wrap">
        <p class="login-img"><i class="icon_lock_alt"></i></p>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_profile"></i></span>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_key_alt"></i></span>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="_password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And my security.yml :

```
security:
role_hierarchy:
  ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
  ROLE_FMTI:        ROLE_FMTI
  ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
access_control:
      - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
      - { path: ^/admin, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

firewalls:
  dev:
      pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false

  secured_area:
      pattern:    ^/admin
      anonymous: ~
      form_login:
          login_path:  /admin/login
          check_path:  /admin/login_check


 access_control:
  - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

 providers:
  in_memory:
      memory:
          users:
              admin: { password: 111111, roles: 'ROLE_FMTI' }

 encoders:
  Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
```

When I tried to access : `/admin/login`

I get this error : `You have requested a non-existent service "request". Did you mean one of these: "router.request_context", "request_stack", "monolog.logger.request", "data_collector.request"?`

Could you please help me ? Thanks in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: Don't forget to vote and choose the right answer, this will help other which are looking for this problem as well!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because you are trying to get a non existent service in your controller. In a symfony controller, you can get the request in the method call :

In your Logincontroller, add this use statement :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
```

And in your function declaration

```
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    // you can directly use $request
    ....
}
```

You can now remove the line where you try to get a non existent service :

```
// remove this line
$request = $this->get('request');
```

Also I'm not sure you will get the session with a get('session'). Based on Symfony' documentation, you should do the following :

```
$session = $request->getSession();
```

see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#managing-the-session

Comment: did you remove the line with $request = $this->get('request'); ?

Comment: Exist another alternative for SecurityContext in symfony3 ?

Comment: Yep but read the docs.  It is all explained and you will keep running into one stumbling block after another if you try to just wing it.  And be sure you only look at Symfony 3 stuff.  Lot's of changes between it and Symfony 2.

Answer (score 17):

Instead of this

```
$this->get('request')
```

Use

```
$this->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()
```

Answer (score 1):

Its exactly what @jiboulex said, complementing it:

Its due to a deprecation of the `$this->getRequest()` which is using the `$this-get('request')` internally.
If you check the migration guide its explicit to do this change:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md#frameworkbundle

Regarding the session you get it via `$this->getSession()` as in the documentation:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#managing-the-session